# Program For Calculating Sin Using Taylor Expansion Not Working?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to write some code that'll calculate the value of sin(0.75) using the Taylor expansion, and print each iteration until the absolute difference between the value calculated using the expansion, and the value calculated using Fortran's intrinsic sin function is less than 1E-6. Here is my code:

```
program taylor
 implicit none
 real :: x = 0.75
 do while (x - sin(0.75) < 10**(-6))
  print *, x
  x = x - ((x**3)/6) + ((x**5)/120) - ((x**7)/5040)
end do
end program taylor
```

However, this doesn't print anything out? Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks too obvious to most people so no-one even wanted to answer, but it should be said explicitly

The condition `x - sin(0.75) < 10**(-6)` is obviously not true when `x` very different from `sin(0.75)`, so the `do while` loop is never entered.

Also, as IanH commented `10**(-6)` will give 0 because the result of  the power of two integers is again an integer. The literal `real` number 10^-6 should be expressed as `1e-6`.

If you change it to `x - sin(0.75) > 1e-6` the loop will proceed, but it will run forever, because your iteration is wrong. Taylor series works differently, you should compute

```
y = 0
y = y + x**1/1!
y = y - x**3/3! 
y = y + x**5/5!
y = y - x**7/7!
...
```

and so on, which is a very different kind of loop.

Try this one:

```
program taylor
 implicit none
 real :: x = 0.75
 real :: y, fact
 integer :: sgn, i

 fact = 1
 sgn = 1

 y = 0

  do i = 1, 10, 2
    y = y + sgn * x**i / fact
    fact = fact*(i+1)*(i+2)
    sgn = -sgn
  end do
  print *, y, sin(x)
end program taylor
```

Comment: Also 10**(-6) == 0.

Comment: May also be worth noting that when you do want to compare two real numbers to check that the difference between them is small enough, you generally want to take the magnitude of the difference, for example `abs(a-b)<c` rather than `a-b<c` (consider `c=1e-6` and `b=1`, the second example would "pass" for any `a`  `<1+1e-6`, such as `a=-100`).