# Program To Calculate Sin(0.75) Using Taylor Series Printing Only 0.75?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm attempting to write a program that calculates the value of sin(0.75) using the Taylor series, until the absolute difference between the calculated value and FORTRAN'S intrinsic sin function is less then 1E-6, printing each iteration to the screen. (it also needs to print the absolute difference at each step, but I haven't gotten round to implementing that yet!). Here's my code:

```
program taylor
implicit none
real :: x = 0.75
if (abs(x - sin(0.75)) > 10.00**(-7)) then
 print *, x
 x = x - ((x**3)/6)
 x = x + ((x**5)/120)
 x = x - ((x**7)/5040)
end if
end program taylor
```

This just prints out 0.75 to the terminal, why is this? How can I fix it so that it does what I specified above?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You print x BEFORE modifying it, that's why the printed value is the initial value of 0.75.   Probably you want two variables, e.g., x and y, and accumulate the Taylor series into y.

Comment: I think you may want to use a while loop instead of an if statement.

Comment: I've added a y value, now it just prints 0.68, which is progress I guess. How would I word the while loop? do while(abs(y - sin(0.75)) > 1E-6?

Comment: @KenWhite, noted, thank you

Comment: Much better. :-) Thank you.

Comment: Is this you or someone else? Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579177/program-for-calculating-sin-using-taylor-expansion-not-working/45586536#45586536

Comment: @VladimirF: I think it's maybe a class exercise at some top-class technical university .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645815/how-to-implement-factorial-function-into-code