# How to implement factorial function into code?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

So I am using the taylor series to calculate sin(0.75) in fortran 90 up until a certain point, so I need to run it in a do while loop (until my condition is met). This means I will need to use a factorial, here's my code:

```
program taylor
implicit none
real :: x = 0.75  
real :: y
integer :: i = 3
do while (abs(y - sin(0.75)) > 10.00**(-7)) 
 i = i + 2
 y = x - ((x**i)/fact(i))
 print *, y
end do
end program taylor
```

Where i've written fact(i) is where i'll need the factorial. Unfortunately, Fortran doesn't have an intrinsic ! function. How would I implement the function in this program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The following simple function answers your question. Note how it returns a `real`, not an integer. If performance is not an issue, then this is fine for the Taylor series.

```
real function fact(n)
  integer, intent(in) :: n

  integer :: i

  if (n < 0) error stop 'factorial is singular for negative integers'
  fact = 1.0
  do i = 2, n
    fact = fact * i
  enddo
end function fact
```

But the real answer is that Fortran 2008 *does* have an intrinsic function for the factorial: [the Gamma function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GAMMA.html). For a positive integer `n`, it is defined such that `Gamma(n+1) == fact(n)`.

(I can imagine the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is unfamiliar. It's a generalization of the factorial function: `Gamma(x)` is defined for all complex `x`, except non-positive integers. The offset in the definition is for historical reasons and unnecessarily confusing it you ask me.)

In some cases you may want to convert the output of the Gamma function to an integer. If so, make sure you use "long integers" via `INT(Gamma(n+1), kind=INT64)` with the `USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_Fortran_env` declaration. This is a precaution against factorials becoming quite large. And, as always, watch out for mixed-mode arithmetic!

Comment: I'd expect the repeated calls to gamma will also be coatly, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. How would I implement this function into my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method to compute n! in one line using only inline functions:

```
product((/(i,i=1,n)/))
```

Of course i must be declared as an integer beforehand. It creates an array that goes from  1 to n and takes the product of all components. Bonus: It even works gives the correct thing for n = 0.

Answer (score 2):

You do NOT want to use a factorial function for your Taylor series. That would meant computing the same terms over and over. You should just multiply the factorial variable in each loop iteration. Don't forget to use `real` because the integer will overflow quickly.

See the answer under the question of your schoolmate [Program For Calculating Sin Using Taylor Expansion Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579177/program-for-calculating-sin-using-taylor-expansion-not-working/45586536#45586536)

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the equation which gives factorial?
It may look something like this

```
PURE FUNCTION Bang(N)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
INTEGER             :: I
INTEGER             :: Bang

Bang = N
IF(N == 2) THEN
  Bang = 2
ELSEIF(N == 1) THEN
  Bang = 1
ELSEIF(N < 1) THEN
  WRITE(*,*)'Error in Bang function N=',N
  STOP
ELSE
  DO I = (N-1), 2, -1
    Bang = Bang * I
  ENDDO
ENDIF

RETURN
END FUNCTION Bang
```

Comment: There are a few issues with this function.  (1) It won't compile, writing to the console from a `pure` procedure is disallowed. (2) It'll only work properly for inputs in a very limited range (figuring out how limited is left as an exercise for the reader), and (3) the `stop` statement stops the program calling the function which is a bit drastic.  Oh, and `factorial(0)` is defined to be equal to `1` and shouldn't cause this type of function to crash.